# How to separately save images from a plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to save each image from a plot to my computer separately.[image]

As shown in image. Each plot have 4 images. I want to save these images to my computer separately.
Code is given below

This the function to Show the images on plot.

```html
def plot_images(**image_cmap_pairs):
    """PLot images in one row"""
    n = len(image_cmap_pairs)
    #plt.figure(figsize=(16, 5))
    for i, (name, image_cmap) in enumerate(image_cmap_pairs.items()):
        image, cmap = image_cmap
        plt.subplot(1, n, i + 1)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.title(' '.join(name.split('_')))
        plt.imshow(image, cmap=cmap)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

And this is the function call code

```html
for i in [100,500,2000]:
    image, mask = augmented_dataset.__getitem__(i)

    plot_images(
        SAR_intensity_0=(image[:, :, 0], 'gray'),
        SAR_intensity_1=(image[:, :, 1], 'gray'),
        building_footprint=(mask[:, :, channel_footprint], 'viridis'),
        building_boundary=(mask[:, :, channel_boundary], 'viridis')
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.imsave` to directly save your image data while applying a colormap.

```
plt.imsave('filename.png', image, cmap=cmap)
```

For example you can include it in your code like this:

```
def plot_images(**image_cmap_pairs):
    """PLot images in one row"""
    n = len(image_cmap_pairs)
    #plt.figure(figsize=(16, 5))
    for i, (name, image_cmap) in enumerate(image_cmap_pairs.items()):
        image, cmap = image_cmap
        plt.imsave(f'image_{i}.png', image, cmap=cmap)
        plt.subplot(1, n, i + 1)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.title(' '.join(name.split('_')))
        plt.imshow(image, cmap=cmap)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked . But now i have another problem, on each iteration of loop and function call it replace the previous images, i want to save them all , is there any way to make folder at each iteration and then 4 images store in that and then and so on.

Comment: Of course there is. Either that or you change the format string for the filename to include the outer loop variable. I can't help you though without some reproducible code.